# Java/Regex - finding a characters anywhere in a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a series of strings that I am searching for a particular combination of characters in. I am looking for a digit, following by the letter m or M, followed by a digit, then followed by the letter f or F.

An example string is - "Class (4) **1m5f** Good" - The text in bold is what I want to extract from the string.

Here is the code I have, that doesn't work.

```
Pattern distancePattern = Pattern.compile("\\^[0-9]{1}[m|M]{1}[0-9]{1}[f|F]{1}$\\");
Matcher distanceMatcher = distancePattern.matcher(raceDetails.toString());
while (distanceMatcher.find()) {
 String word= distanceMatcher.group(0);
 System.out.println(word);
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` ...

Comment: also, you don't need `{1}` after the character classes. `[0-9]` on its own means "once".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b\d[mM]\d[fF]\b
```

for java, backslashes are to be escaped:

```
\\b\\d[mM]\\d[fF]\\b
```

`{1}` is superfluous
`[m|M]` means `m`or `|` or `M`

Comment: The slashes needed escaping in Java ("\\b\\d[mM]\\d[fF]\\b"), but other than that, perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` and `$` characters at the start and end of your regex are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) - they're limiting you to strings that only consist of the pattern you're looking for. The first step is to remove those.

You can then either use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to limit the pattern you're looking for to be an entire word, like this:

```
Pattern distancePattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d[mM]\\d[fF]\\b");
```

...or, if you don't mind your pattern appearing in the middle of a word, e.g., "Class (4) a1m5f Good", you can drop the word boundaries:

```
Pattern distancePattern = Pattern.compile("\\d[mM]\\d[fF]");
```

Quick notes:

- You don't really need the `{1}`s everywhere - the default assumption
  is that a character or character class is happening once.
- You can
  replace the `[0-9]` character class with `\d` (it means the same
  thing).
- Both links are to regular-expressions.info, a great resource for learning about regexes that I highly recommend you check out :)

Comment: Fantastic explanation, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For the requirement of `a digit, following by the letter m or M, followed by a digit, then followed by the letter f or F` regex can be simplified to:

```
Pattern distancePattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\dm\\df");
```

Where:

```
(?i) - For ignore case
\\d  - For digits [0-9]
```